# Crear una tabla si no existe e ingresar datos en una tabla al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

como podran apreciar el mi codigo, me gustaria que al ingresar cierto datos, con el select o $sqlsel, verifique si hay algun campo que tenga ese Nusuario ingresado y que si no lo hay entonces se pueda ingresar una fila con los datos indicados y crear una tabla aparte con los datos especificados, ando un oco laguneado, aqui les dejo el ejemplo:

```
<?php
include("db1.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['nusuario'])){
$nusuario = $_POST['nusuario'];
}
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
$nnombre = $_POST['nombre'];
}
if(isset($_POST['nrol'])){
$nrol = $_POST['nrol'];
}

$tabla = 'usuarios';

$sqlsel = "SELECT * FROM `$tabla` WHERE Nusuario = '$nusuario'";
$consulta = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlsel);

if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) == 0){

$sqlcr = "CREATE TABLE IF NO EXISTS '$nusuario' (`IDTécnico` int(250) NOT     
NULL AUTO INCREMENT, `Fecha` date NOT NULL, `Proveniencia` varchar(60) utf8 
NOT NULL,`Dirección` varchar(60) utf8 NOT NULL, `Departamento` varchar(60) 
utf8 NOT NULL, `Oficina` varchar(60) utf8 NOT NULL, `Atencion` 
varchar(60)utf8 NOT NULL, `Tiempo de solución` varchar(50) utf8 NOT NULL, 
`Descripción del problema` MEDIUMTEXT utf8 NOT NULL, `Solución` MEDIUMTEXT 
utf8 NOT NULL)";
$consulta1 = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlcr);

$sqlin = "INSERT INTO `$tabla` (`IDuser`, `Nombre`, `Nusuario`, `Rol`) VALUES 

(NULL, '$nnombre', '$nusuario', '$nrol')";
$consulta2 = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlin);
}
else{
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../mop/indexcu1.html'";
}
?>
```

Y cuando ejecuto, no me muestra error alguno, tan solo me muestra pantalla en blanco y ahí queda, claro, así debería ser, pero tampoco me crea ni la tabla, ni ingresa los datos en la tabla
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a este problema está en la doble validación innecesaria que en su momento intente darle al codigo, cuál era la intención? Crear un nuevo usuario, entonces, intentaba consultar la existencia de un usuario en una tabla `usuarios` con

````
$sqlsel = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE Nusuario = '$nusuario'";
$consulta = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlsel);
if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) == 0)```

Y luego volvía a validar en la sentencia SQL 

```$sqlcr = "CREATE TABLE IF NO EXISTS '$nusuario' (IDTécnico int(250) NOT     
NULL AUTO INCREMENT, Fecha date NOT NULL, Proveniencia varchar(60) utf8 
NOT NULL, Dirección varchar(60) utf8 NOT NULL,  Departamento  varchar(60) 
utf8 NOT NULL, Oficina varchar(60) utf8 NOT NULL, Atencion 
varchar(60)utf8 NOT NULL, Tiempo de solución varchar(50) utf8 NOT NULL, 
Descripción del problema MEDIUMTEXT utf8 NOT NULL, Solución MEDIUMTEXT 
utf8 NOT NULL)";
$consulta1 = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlcr);```.

Cuando realmente lo mas fácil y correcto es verificar si existe el usuario en la tabla usuarios de igual manera:

```$sqlsel = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Nusuario = '$nusuario'";
$consulta = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlsel);
if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) == 0)```

Y si la consulta devuelve 0 entonces, se procede a insertar los datos en la tabla principal que sería usuarios:

```$sqlin = "INSERT INTO `$tabla` (`IDuser`, `Nombre`, `Nusuario`, `Rol`) VALUES (NULL, '$nnombre', '$nusuario', '$nrol')";
$consulta2 = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlin);``` 

y justo después de la insertar el usuario en la tabla principal en codigo, pasar a crear la tabla del usuario, pero sin la validación ```CREATE TABLE IF NO EXISTS```, porque se supone que la tabla guía es 'usuarios' y si no existe ahí el usuario, no debería existir tabla para el usuario insertar información: 

```$sqlcr = "CREATE TABLE '$nusuario' (`IDTécnico` int(250) NOT     
NULL AUTO INCREMENT, `Fecha` date NOT NULL, `Proveniencia` varchar(60) utf8 
NOT NULL,`Dirección` varchar(60) utf8 NOT NULL, `Departamento` varchar(60) 
utf8 NOT NULL, `Oficina` varchar(60) utf8 NOT NULL, `Atencion` 
varchar(60)utf8 NOT NULL, `Tiempo de solución` varchar(50) utf8 NOT NULL, 
`Descripción del problema` MEDIUMTEXT utf8 NOT NULL, `Solución` MEDIUMTEXT 
utf8 NOT NULL)";
$consulta1 = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sqlcr);```

Y así si debería funcionar y con mejores prácticas u orden.
````

Answer (score 0):

Hola talvez el problema este en la forma en que estas armando la sentencia sql dado que deberías de concatenar las variables con un puto (.) Es decir:

```
$sqlsel = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabla". WHERE Nusuario = '".$nusuario."'";
```